# sql query to count multiple rows group by type

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Perhaps a non-trivial query, I'm using this table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0423 and trying to output the following table using mysql 5.6

```
[type][type_cnt][f_cnt_type0][f_cnt_type1][f_cnt_type2][time_00][time_00-15][time_15-30]
10        2         1             1           0           1          1          0
20        3         1             1           1           1          2          0
30        3         2             1           0           0          1          1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like simple `GROUP BY` with columns like this: `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE 0 END)`. In MySQL it's also possible to use `COUNT(Boolean expression)`.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : Not sure why this was marked down.  I did Mitch.  I can do several queries type, count('column') and group by type, but not sure how I could do the others one statement or nested statements.  If you'd like to help, it's highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE bugs (
     type varchar(2),
     flag varchar(1), 
     mins varchar(2)
 );

INSERT INTO bugs(type, flag, mins) values
('10','0','0'),
('10','1','5'),
('20','0','0'),
('20','1','5'),
('20','2','10'),
('30','0','10'),
('30','0','20'),
('30','1','40');


select 
  type, 
  count(type) as type_cnt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN flag='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as f_cnt_type0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN flag='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as f_cnt_type1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN flag='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as f_cnt_type2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(mins AS UNSIGNED) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as time_00,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(mins AS UNSIGNED) > 0 and CAST(mins AS UNSIGNED) <= 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as time_00_15,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(mins AS UNSIGNED) > 15 and CAST(mins AS UNSIGNED) <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as time_15_30       
from bugs
group by type
```

SQL : [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0423/20/0)